# SPContext.Current vs SPContext.GetContext

Tags: spcontext, guidance

To get current *SP* objects (SPWeb, SPSite, SPList etc), I generally use *SPContext.Current*. In some situations, *SPContext.GetContext* is preferred because  *SPContext.Current* have many objects null depending on where the code runs (Webpart page, Edit item form etc).

Are you aware of any guidelines (may be from Microsoft) on the usage *SPContext.Current* and *SPContext.GetContext* ?

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for using the SPContext.GetContext is to set the context of a control to one that is different than the context of the current page.  For example, you can set the ItemFieldIterator.ItemContext proprty to get information from a list on different SPWeb object.

```
myItemFieldIterator.ItemContext = SPContext.GetContext(Context, 0, ListId, oSPWeb);
```

Answer (score 1):

`SPContext.GetContext` tends to be used if there is no current context (console app? timer job? FeatureUninstalling?), whereby in the case where you do, you would use the obviously named `SPContext.Current`.

Comment: Good point.I think what you said is specific to SPContext.GetContext(SPWeb) version, all other overloaded versions require HttpContext...which is not there in Console,timer etc.